# Flink 1.9 stoppable function is been removed

Tags: apache-flink

we are moving from 1.8.2 to flink 1.9 but i see org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.StoppableFunction is been removed .what is the alternate approach to do this in flink 1.9 .

we have a custom event emitter function whcih extends RichParallelSourceFunction implements StoppableFunction.

Comment: What do you exactly need?

Comment: we basically  have custom event emitter function which extends RichParallelSourceFunction<JsonNode> implements StoppableFunction.since now the stoppable function is removed we dont have a way to stop .

Comment: @SindhuShree, were you able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop a source from emitting records (and being closed by the system) simply quit the `run` method.

As a template consider the `FromIteratorFunction` that just emits the records of an `Iterator`.

```java
    public class FromIteratorFunction<T> implements SourceFunction<T> {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private final Iterator<T> iterator;

        private volatile boolean isRunning = true;

        public FromIteratorFunction(Iterator<T> iterator) {
            this.iterator = iterator;
        }

        @Override
        public void run(SourceContext<T> ctx) throws Exception {
            while (isRunning && iterator.hasNext()) {
                ctx.collect(iterator.next());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void cancel() {
            isRunning = false;
        }
    }
```